# Javascript array becomes undefined right after correct console output

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function that draws a chart with the given data. The data is passed with a parameter. The function looks like this:

```
drawCustomChart(element, data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        element.append(
            `<div class="chart__item--${data[i][1]}">
                <div class="chart__item__tag">${data[i][0]}</div>
                <div class="chart__item__bar">
                    <div class="chart__item__bar__inner" style="width: ${data[i][2]}%" data-chart-bar="${data[i][1]}"></div>
                    <div class="chart__item__bar__tooltip chart__item__bar__tooltip--${data[i][1]}" data-tooltip="${data[i][1]}">
                        <div class="chart__item__bar__tooltip__arrow"></div>
                        <span class="chart__item__bar__tooltip__label">${data[i][0]}: ${data[i][2]}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chart__item__label">${data[i][2]}</div>
            </div>`
        );
    }
}
```

I call the function with the following code:

```
// The function call
drawElectionResultsChart(electionResultsChartData);

// The function that's being called
drawElectionResultsChart(data) {
    helpers.drawCustomChart($$.voteCountsChart, data);
}
```

The data that is passed to drawElectionResultsChart(data) is a two-dimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array[13]
    0: Array[3]
    1: Array[3]
    2: Array[3]
    3: Array[3]
    4: Array[3]
    5: Array[3]
    6: Array[3]
    7: Array[3]
    8: Array[3]
    9: Array[3]
    10: Array[3]
    11: Array[3]
    12: Array[3]
    length:  13
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

Each array inside the main array contains three values. The problem is this. On the line that console.logs the array (`console.log(data)`) inside the drawCustomChart function it works fine and the array gets logged. However, right after the log it executes the console.log again for some reason and then it says `undefined`. Because the array suddenly becomes undefined, the drawCustomChart method outputs an error about `data.length` (because `data` is now undefined).

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
drawCustomChart(element, data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        element.append(
            `<div class="chart__item--${data[i][1]}">
                <div class="chart__item__tag">${data[i][0]}</div>
                <div class="chart__item__bar">
                    <div class="chart__item__bar__inner" style="width: ${data[i][2]}%" data-chart-bar="${data[i][1]}"></div>
                    <div class="chart__item__bar__tooltip chart__item__bar__tooltip--${data[i][1]}" data-tooltip="${data[i][1]}">
                        <div class="chart__item__bar__tooltip__arrow"></div>
                        <span class="chart__item__bar__tooltip__label">${data[i][0]}: ${data[i][2]}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chart__item__label">${data[i][2]}</div>
            </div>`
        );
    }
}
```